# got multiple values for keyword argument 'response' - django

Tags: python, django, arguments, response, keyword

I am getting this error
`json_response_message() got multiple values for keyword argument 'response'`

I figured how I get this error though but I just cannot find out a workaround for this, is there anyone able to give me a hand?

the reason for this error is because of this line

```
return json_response_message(success_response(), response=response)
```

these are the two functions I created and they work fine though,

```
def json_response_message(response, **kwargs):
    data = {}
    print(response)
    print(kwargs)
    data.update(response)
    data.update(kwargs)

    return JsonResponse(data)


def success_response(*args):
    # initial message to ok
    message = 'OK'

    # if there is *args then add this to the message
    if args:
        for value in args:
            message += value

    return {
        'status': True,
        'code': 200,
        'message': message
    }
```

I figured if I do something like this, everything would work fine

```
return json_response_message(success_response(), change_this=response)
```

is it because `response` is a reserved word or something? either way, is there a way I can still make it happen to be `response=response` ? Because all the structure in front end has already been set up.  I don't really want to change anything if I don't have to as long as I have some workaround on my side.

Can someone please give me a hand?  Thanks in advance

Comment: having asked so many questions already you should know by now that a full stacktrace should be included.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error message says everything: `json_response_message() got multiple values for keyword argument 'response'`

Your function definition header `def json_response_message(response, **kwargs):` says that value of first(positional) parameter will be placed to the `response` variable. And then you are trying to pass second argument( keyword argument) to your function call(`json_response_message(success_response(), response=response)`) with name corresponding to the `response` - which was already assigned by the value returned from `success_response()`

Comment: ah! totally get what you mean after explaining.  Thanks thanks